# Static files are not served during production in Django. How to solve the issue?

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, web-deployment

I want to deploy a Django app in my Linux server. I followed the Django docs and even configured the Apache config file as well but when running the Django server, *none of my CSS and JS files are seen for: my website, Django admin interface and rest_framework as well.*

**This is what I had done so far:**

**A 'static' folder was created after initating the 'collectstatic' command and contains the following:**

```
blog_app (my website)
rest_framework (my APIs)
admin (Default Django Admin interface)
```

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False

[.] #all default settings

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

**Apache config file (I named it as 'django_app.conf'):**

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

#django_app is the root folder for my Django project
Alias /static /var/user/django_app/static
  <Directory /var/user/django_app/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/user/django_app/django_app>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/user/django_app/django_app/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess my_django_app python-path=/var/user/django_app python-home=/var/user/django_app/venv
  WSGIProcessGroup my_django_app
```

**After this, I typed:**

```
sudo a2ensite django.conf        #to allow my Apache config file instead of 000-default.conf
```

**And:**

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf  #to disallow original Apache2 config file
```

**Then I included www-data user permission for my root project folder:**

```
sudo chown :www-data /var/user/django_app/
```

**And I also included read, write and execute permissions for my root Django project:**

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/user/django_app/
```

**After this, I executed this command:**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Finally, I executed the Django server inside my root folder:**

```
python3 manage.py runserver <IP Address>:8000
```

However, when looking at my website, Django admin interface and Django Rest Framework HTML pages, there are no static files involved (CSS and JS files are missing).

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing it inside your project folder place it one folder up as shown and create static-root folder and media folder there, run the collectstatic command.

```
Alias /static /var/static-root
<Directory /var/static-root>
   Require all granted
 </Directory>

Alias /media /var/media-root
<Directory /var/media-root>
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and do some changes in your setting file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/static-root/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/media-root/'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try this. However, just one doubt, I thought it was a standard to place the static folder within a root project? Should I change the permissions of the static folder after following your method?

Comment: For media you may have to give user permissions in case of error.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. Could it be that I no longer need to access the Django server and just move forward with the Apache and insert the IP address in the URL? Is that the reason why the site remains broken?

Comment: I have already included the following update in my code already, but the static url is still not directing to the required folder.

Comment: you run collectstatic command? checked the new static folders? is any files there or empty?

Comment: Yes, I did run the command. Every file is there as expected. But the problem is that the url is not pointing towards that particular folder. Instead, it's pointing towards another folder inside my root project folder (within the blog_app static folder).

Comment: in urls you have to add this if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Still doesnt work :( Should I change the DocumentRoot inside my Apache config file?